# Why is the answer of the problem 0.57, rather than 1.57?

Tags: probability, random-variables

See [this video at 4:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BswLMKgXzU).

[image]

According to me, the result should be $1.57$.

$P(X \ge 1.8)$
$ = F(4) - F(1.8) + 1$ (as we have $X>4 = 1$)
$ = 1.57$

Why is the answer of the problem $0.57$, rather than $1.57$?

Comment: You expect the probability to be more than 1?  More than certain?

Comment: Why do you add one? I don't understand that.

Comment: @Eff, good question. $X \ge 1.8$ means the value of $X$ exceeds $4$.

Comment: @badjohn, $X \ge 1.8$ means the value of $X$ exceeds $4$. So, why not include $1$?

Comment: I considered an answer but others have done so now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the answer should be $0.57$. First and foremost, the answer cannot be more than $1$. Thats a violation of conservation of probability. 
So the additional $+1$ that you mention in your answer is wrong and not needed, since $F(X>4)=1$ but $P(X>4)=0$. So you need not add the $1$. To prove this statement of mine, note that
$$P(X>1.8)=F(X=4)-F(X=1.8)$$
$$=F(X=\infty)-F(X=1.8)$$

It means that the cumulative probability distribution reaches 1, i.e. the sum of all the probabilities reach 1 on crossing X=4. So the cumulative probability function saturates at X=4 with a value of 1. There is no further contribution to F from any point X>4. This implies that P=0 for X>4. And if P=0 in that region, then there is no need for you to add 1 for X>4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "... , since $F(X>4)=1$ but $P(X>4)=0$." --- what do you mean? Kindly rephrase.

Comment: It means that the cumulative probability distribution reaches 1, i.e. the sum of all the probabilities reach 1 on crossing X=4. So the cumulative probability function saturates at X=4 with a value of 1. There is no further contribution to F from any point X>4. This implies that P=0 for X>4. And if P=0 in that region, then there is no need for you to add 1 for X>4.

Comment: Kindly, add this comment to the main answer so that I can accept this.

Comment: @user366312 Done.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply
$$
\begin{align}
P(X\geq 1.8) &= 1-P(X<1.8)\\
&= 1- F(1.8)\\
&= 1-\frac{1}{32}\left(6\cdot1.8^2-1.8^3\right)\\
&\approx 0.57
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $X \ge 1.8$ means the value of $X$ exceeds $4$.

Comment: @user366312 I must admit that I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at.The value 1.8 does not exceed 4, it's less than 4. But even if it did, I don't understand why it's relevant.

Comment: I guess that he is thinking that $X \ge 1.8$ means that $X$ might exceed $4$.  Of course, for this particular distribution it won't.

Comment: @badjohn I suppose. But even if could exceed 4, I don't understand how it is relevant. I don't think I understand OP's reasoning.

Comment: @Eff I just wondering that it might be the source of his confusion not that I thought that he was right.  Clearly he isn't since he calculated a probability of more than $1$.

Comment: @badjohn Yeah, I understand that you don't think they are right. But maybe you understood their reasoning. For example, if the formula for $F$ was completely different from $x\geq 2$ and extended further out than $4$, my answer would still hold.

Comment: @Eff My best guess is that the piecewise definition of the distribution has caused the confusion.  The OP has failed to realise that it is only the value of the CDF at $4$ that matters. The definition could be slightly simplified by changing the cases to: $x \le 0$, $0 \lt x \lt 4$, and $x \ge 4$.  That might help.